# Trying to print, but says my function name is not defined?

Tags: python

```
name = str(input("What is your name? "))
age = int(input("What is your age? "))
weight_float = float(input("What is your weight in pounds? "))
height_float = float(input("What is your height in inches? "))

Pounds2Kilogram = weight_float * 0.453592
Inches2Meter = height_float * 0.0254

weight = Pounds2Kilogram
height = Inches2Meter


class calcBMI:
        
    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, height):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__height = height
    
    def getBMI(self):
        return self.__weight / (self.__height **2)
    
    def getStatus(self):
        if getBMI() < 18.5:
            self.__getStatus = "Underweight"
        elif 18.5 < getBMI() < 24.9:
            self.__getStatus = "Normal"
        elif 25.0 < getBMI() < 29.9:
            self.__getStatus = "Overweight"
        elif getBMI() > 30:
            self.__getStatus = "Obese"
    
    def getName(self):
        return self.__name
    
    def getAge(self):
        return self.__age
    
    def getWeight(self):
        return self.__weight
    
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.__height
    

a = calcBMI(name, age, weight, height)     
print("The BMI for ", a.getName(), " is ", a.getBMI(), "which is ", a.getStatus())
```

I have a bit of an issue when trying to print for this BMI calculator, at the very end it should look like,

"The BMI for (name) is (BMI number), which is (status, basically if they're underweight, overweight etc.)"

#### In the getStatus() i am trying to take the numeric value from getBMI() and use it in the if statement. (I don't know why this is big and bold lettered)

The problem arises when I try to print, it's prompts me to input my name, age, weight, and height like normal.

This is what it outputs: **`NameError: name 'getBMI' is not defined`**

Comment: `if self.getBMI() < 18.5` etc. Use `self` to refer to methods and attributes, also inside a method.

Comment: Side note: The middle sentence is big and bold lettered due to the underline you placed under the sentence, which the markup interpreted it as a [header](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers)

Comment: @downshift ohh, I see, thank you!

Comment: @TheIllusion sure, and if you want to edit it, just select that sentence and repeatedly press "CTRL+H" to get the size you want. cheers on getting your code working! :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in the `getStatus` function, you are calling `getBmi` but you should be calling `self.getBmi()`

The `getStatus` function should look like this:

```
def getStatus(self):
    if self.getBMI() < 18.5:
        self.__getStatus = "Underweight"
    elif 18.5 < self.getBMI() < 24.9:
        self.__getStatus = "Normal"
    elif 25.0 < self.getBMI() < 29.9:
        self.__getStatus = "Overweight"
    elif self.getBMI() > 30:
        self.__getStatus = "Obese"
    return self.__getStatus
```

Also, as `input` automatically returns a string, you can just say

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
```

Comment: Make sure you include the `return self.__getStatus` line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`getBMI` is not defined as a global function, and so a `NameError` is thrown when you try to refer to it as just `getBMI`. The method of this name cannot be referenced nakedly like this in the way that C++ methods can.  Instead, an instance must refer to its methods as attributes of `self`, i.e. as `self.getBMI()` in this case.